# Finding matches inserted in lists and maintaining the order in subsequent lists

Tags: python, list

I was handed a bunch of lists that contain data of 3D curves. The curve starts out very very small, and the longer a curve is in the list, the bigger it gets.

The problem is that all these lists start out with everything in order, but then new items get inserted, not appended.

The tricky part is that I need to track what items get *bumped* further down the list. So if in `list1=[A, B, C]` a new letter gets inserted like `list2=[A, D, B, C]`, I need to know that `list2[3]` is the same as `list1[2]` and then in subsequent lists maintain that until a new item is inserted and offsets *that* one.

In my case, I have other attributes, like size, that can help determine where a new item was added specifically. If it's small size (e.g. 0.01), it's new. But size isn't enough to match, since it's similar to others. So I'd like to rework the ordering to track things.

```
List_0 = [[1, 0.01], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0]]
List_1 = [[1, 1.1], [2, 1.2], [3, 1.12]]
List_2 = [[1, 2.3], [2, 2.23], [4, 0.01], [5,0.02], [3,2.25]
List_3 = [[6, 0.01], [1, 3.45], [2, 3.54], [4, 1.12], [5, 1.11], [3,3.65]]
```

This example is simple, but this scales to 1000's of entries in the lists. It seems like a really simple reordering/remapping issue, but I'm racking my brain trying to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you’ve tried and the problem you’re facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by comparing the new list to the previous list length, and if the new list is longer then there is a new item (or items). I'm detecting the new items specifically by checking their size against a limit. And then I'm updating the "match list" which tells me what new item got added where and in what order it was added.

I was originally overthinking this and assuming I needed to track the list order across *all* lists. But I only need to track it against the previous list.

```
my_Lists = [[[1, 0.01], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0]], 
            [[1, 1.1], [2, 1.2], [3, 1.12]], 
            [[1, 2.3], [2, 2.23], [4, 0.01], [5, 0.02], [3, 2.25]], 
            [[6, 0.01], [1, 3.45], [2, 3.54], [4, 1.12], [5, 1.11], [3,3.65]]
            ]

longest_List_Index = len(my_Lists[0])
prev_Match_List = []
match_List = [] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] or when updated [0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4]

for index, my_List in enumerate(my_Lists):
    
    if index == 0:
        
        for pos, sub_List in enumerate(my_List):
            match_List.append(sub_List[0])
        print "Base list #1"
        print "\t" + "Prev match: " + str(prev_Match_List) + " " + "New match: "  + str(match_List)
        print ""
        prev_Match_List = match_List[:]
            
    else:
        
        if len(my_List) > longest_List_Index:
            longest_List_Index = len(my_List)
            print "Detected longer list in list #" + str(index)

            for pos, sub_List in enumerate(my_List):         
                if sub_List[1] > 0 and sub_List[1] < .1:
                    found_New = True
                    print "\tNew entry at index: " + str(pos), sub_List      
                    match_List.insert(pos, sub_List[0])
                    

            if found_New:
                print "\t" + "Prev match: " + str(prev_Match_List) + " " + "New match: "  + str(match_List)
                
                # update the match list
                prev_Match_List = match_List[:]
                
            print ""
```